# How can I convert videos in php without using ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I made a code in php that extracts mp3 audio track from a video file using the `exec` function to execute `ffmpeg`.

All works fine on a local server using WAMP on windows. But when deploying the script to the server, I can not run `ffmpeg` anymore because the server does not have the software.

Is there a class in pure PHP, or an API that is capable of the same or at least the basic ffmpeg functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when deploying the script to the server, I can not run `ffmpeg` anymore because the server does not have the software.

It's easy to get `ffmpeg` on your server:

1. [Download a static build of `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for Linux, Windows, or OS X.
2. Point your script to it.
3. Encode.

See [FFmpeg Wiki: PHP](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/PHP).

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

As any conversion is very CPU intensive, there is no pure PHP solution and in near future never will be.

Comment: If this post answered your question, please mark it as as answer.

Comment: The question already said that ffmpeg isn't installed on the server!

Comment: As I have written, any encoding/decoding of video is CPU intensive and external compiled binary is required. So you have to install it.

Comment: So then why are you mentioning the library? If the answer is "no", just say that; don't send the OP down a blind alley trying to install a library that won't work.

Comment: @duskwuff ok, I tried to provide best possible answer. The answer is you still need the binary, there is an extentions for PHP and also some wrapper for it. I also edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For conversion you can use https://cloudconvert.com/ that provides rest api and asyncronous conversions.

Answer (score 0):

First your question title mentions "videos", but the question body asks about MP3s, could you please clarify?

Second, just because the server does not have **ffmpeg** this does not mean you cannot install it. This probably should be the option to pursue - and if the host is that strict, it is unlikely you'd be able to install any other solution anyway.

PHP as a language does not have MP3 decoders, and while it is possible to write one, or even to find one already written, I would avoid it. Parsing multimedia formats is tricky, as recent Stagefright bug in Android proved, so you'd be better using a well-tested and supported frameworks such as GStreamer or FFMpeg.

Also if you need to convert only certain formats such as MP3, you can look at MP3 decoders such as lame.